# Is there a formula or calculating the maximum monthly withdrawal from an investment so that it lasts a specific period of time?

Tags: investing

Is there a formula that allows me to calculate the following:-

I have an investment balance of **P** growing at annual rate of **r**, what is the monthly withdrawal so that at the end of **T** years the balance is 0.

Comment: See the annuity due formula on this similar question: [How do I equally disburse appreciating assets over a fixed timeframe?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/101837/how-do-i-equally-disburse-appreciating-assets-over-a-fixed-timeframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's convert everything to months:

```
r' = r ^ (1/12), the monthly rate
T' = 12 * T, the number of months
```

The convention is that r and r' are (1 + rate as a decimal). We can assume monthly compounding for simplicity's sake. We can write a system:

```
B(0) = P
B(i + 1) = r' * B(i) - x
B(T') = r' * B(T' - 1) - x = 0
```

Here, x is the constant monthly withdrawal. To get a closed-form expression, we write out a few terms:

```
i    B(i)
0    P
1    r'P - x
2    r'r'P - r'x - x
3    r'r'r'P - r'r'x - r'x - x
...
k    (r' ^ k) * P - x * (r' ^ k - 1) / (r' - 1)
```

Here, we used the partial sum formula for a geometric series to get a closed-form expression for the sum of powers of r'. Note: if r' = 1, that is, the interest rate is 0%, this does not work; however, in that case, x = P / T'. Now we simply substitute this in fir the term k = T' and solve for x:

```
(r' ^ T') * P - x * (r' ^ T' - 1) / (r' - 1) = 0
x = P * (r' ^ T') * (r' - 1) / (r' ^ T' - 1)
```

This matches our intuition in a couple of important ways:
- x is directly proportional to P
- x is strictly greater than P * (r' - 1), which would be the withdrawal rate to leave the principal balance unchanged.

For instance: if you have $1,000,000 and a safe 5% APR compounded monthly and you want to take equal withdrawals monthly for 30 years, then your monthly withdrawal is about $5,300.

Note: this is the same calculation for doing mortgage amortization, just in reverse.

Comment: Note that your r' might be 1 + (r - 1) / 12, rather than my number. This increases the above example to ~$5,368/mo.

Comment: Patrick it was exactly this I needed to conver to effective periodic rate before applying to the amortization formula.

Comment: If the APR is 5% _compounded monthly_ , then `r'` is 5/12 and not the twelfth root of `r`.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I contemplate that possibility in the comment above. It really comes down to what the r means. But yes, however determined, r' is the monthly rate and this calculation assumes monthly compounding.

Comment: The point is that if r is the effective annual yield (APY), then r' is the twelfth root of r if you want to assume that the yield is added on in 12 monthly installments, while if r is the "APR compounded monthly" then r' is r/12. It is not clear which the OP meant, and we get a completely different calculation if the yield is credited annually (as with dividend distributions from a mutual fund) while the withdrawals are monthly (as the OP desires).

Comment: @DilipSarwate I see what you're saying now, I incorrectly used APR in the example at the end. Good catch. Also, yes, this assumes monthly compounding; compunding annually or continuously or any way but monthly would give a different result. However, at least for discrete compounding, this is illustrative of the method of calculation: it would be easy to change the system for annual, semimonthly, etc. compounding, assuming one knows how to get the rate and number of periods. I think this - showing why the formulas work, how to get them - is what other answers I've seen here lack.

Comment: (possibly the asker agreed, at least)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming that the annual rate r is being quoted as an APR compounded monthly (that is, at the end of the month, the balance you have increases by r/12th of the balance at the beginning of the month before being brought down by your monthly withdrawal, you can use the *loan amortization formula* that calculates the monthly payment due on a loan of $P at an APR of r compounded monthly and due to be paid off in T years.  Any number of *bank loan calculators* freey available on the web will do the calculation for you.

Comment: I'm looking for a formula not a calculator?
The loan amortization formula doesn't behave as expected.